# how to visualize directed graph edge weights comparatively

Tags: tables

I have a directed weighted graph such as:

```
edge(A, B, 1)
edge(A, C, 3)
edge(B, A, -1)
edge(B, C, -1)
edge(C, A, -2)
edge(C, B, -4)
```

So I created an html table matrix where I use `rgb(normalized_weight* 255/ min_max_diff, 0, 255- normalized_weight* 255/ min_max_diff)` as color. That gives me a bright red when weight is high and bright blue when it is low. Shades of purple for in-between values.

The problem is when I have a 500x500 matrix and the boxes 1.5 cm wide on the screen (because column headers are so wide), people get lost in the matrix looking for the bright colors.

So I need some sort of user interface for them to easily nagivate inside the map and find interesting regions.

I was thinking of a minimap, but 500x500 already covers half the screen. What can I do to ease navigation and provide guidance in this huge table of colors?

Here's what the matrix currently looks like:

[image]

Comment: Does your matrix is the incidence matrix? What do you mean under interesting regions? Can you provide some screenshots?

Comment: @AlexeyKolchenko yes, it is the incidence matrix with weights, but it shows colors instead of numbers. Adding screenshot now.

Comment: Interesting boxes are the ones which have brighter colors (red or blue, not purple)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution is:

- **Display the whole matrix on a screen**
- **Use interactive visualization controls**, see image

[image]

Comment: OK this gave me an idea. I add your positive/negative filters to the page and a minimap to navigate to their exact location